# Get up to speed with Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, migration, spring-3

I've been working so far with Spring 2.5.x and it's time to move to Spring 3 so I need some good resources for making the migration as quickly as possible.

Although there are some good books mentioned here on SO, what I actually need is something that will just present me the "new picture" without reiterating information learned with Spring 2.5.x. and so far I wasn't able to find something good.

Do you know of such resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the project docs to be useful.  They're a good place to start and branch out from if you need more info on specific topics.  A quick overview of the new features of Spring 3 can be found here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html

Comment: It seems that indeed the reference documentation is the place to start. I was trying "to cheat" a bit and go straight for the changes, but so far I haven't found a good migration guide so I'll go for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

There is not too much new to spring 3. Here's a list of what I consider important:

- `@Value` annotation - allows you to inject primitives
- RESTful style for spring-mvc. This is not actually new in spring 3, but it is emphasized and improved
- SPeL - this is in conjunction with the first point. You have an expression language that you can use throughout your configuration
- JSR-330 support - that's `@Inject`, `@Qualifier` and the likes.

There are other minor improvements, that you will find throughout your work.

Spring 3.1 adds another two important things:

- caching abstraction - use `@Cacheable` on spring methods so that their invocation is cached
- environment-specific beans. You can have some beans active depending on whether it is development or production.

My migration from 2.5 to 3.0 was smooth - I just started using `@Inject`, `@Value` and by looking at the reference documentation, discovering some other minor improvements.

Comment: As far as I have seen so far, Spring 3 uses a lot of annotations. Has it moved away from XML configuration? I now I can use both, and the XML overrides the annotations, but can I only use XML configuration without annotations (or keeping them to a minimum)?

Comment: @ElenaT - nothing has changed in terms of annotations and xml since spring 2.5. Yes, it is a bit more custom to use annotations now, but not because of what spring offeres.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring Blog](http://blog.springsource.com/category/spring/30/) was very interesting when Spring 3.0 (Milestones) was released (autumn of 2009 till middle of 2010). They show the new Features in some examples.

Except of the new features mentioned by Bonzo, in my humble opinion the most important change was to use Annotations instead of XML as the major default configuration style. XML still works (and there are also some improvements (new namespaces)) and it is at lest as power full as Annotations, but I feel that Annotations are now the more preferred style.